# How to write value in some specific column in ArcGIS table?

Tags: python, scripting, arcgis

I am writing a python script to add fields and write data into the ArcGIS table. I can successfully edit and delete columns or fields in the table. But I am stuck at writing data into the fields. I got a code by which we can get the type and others info about the fields. But I was unable to write something on that particular field.

Here is the script I got from their forum -

```
import arcpy

feature_class = "c:/data/counties.shp"

# Create a list of fields using the ListFields function
fields = arcpy.ListFields(feature_class)

# Iterate through the list of fields
for field in fields:
    # Print field properties
    print("Field:       {0}".format(field.name))
    print("Alias:       {0}".format(field.aliasName))
    print("Type:        {0}".format(field.type))
    print("Is Editable: {0}".format(field.editable))
    print("Required:    {0}".format(field.required))
    print("Scale:       {0}".format(field.scale))
    print("Precision:   {0}".format(field.precision))
```

**Updated**
The picture below is the table I have
[image]

My Primary Key is **COPROPCD** and I want to change the other fields based on my other dataset which has the common primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update a record you need the [UpdateCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) method. Assuming your `datasource` is a dictioanry you could do

```
import arcpy
feature_class = "c:/data/counties.shp"

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature_class, ["COPROPCD","field2"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        #Check if "COPROPCD" exist as a key in the dict     
        if row[0] in dataset.keys():
            #logic for updating the dable
            #This will update the field2 column to the value of the key
            row[1] = dataset["value"]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: My scenario is a little bit different, I have a primary key and some external data. And I need to insert values into some fields if the key matches on both data set.

Comment: you can still do that. you could create a dictionary and if the field is the same as the key you update the fields you need with the values of the dict

Comment: Can you show some example codes? I am really confused and new to python.

Comment: put some line of the input file in your example and the fields related to the shapefile

Comment: I have updated my question with a picture of my table.